# ARIMAX with a specified nonlinear model using the arima function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, nonlinear-regression

I am interested in fitting an ARIMAX model using R.
As known, ARIMAX can be understood as a composition of ARIMA models and regression models with exogenous (independent) variables. I have a time series $Y_i$, and want to estimate the ARIMA and nonlinear coefficients. The nonlinear model is the following:

$y_i=β_0+β_1t_i+β_2d+β_3 sin(2πt_i/β_4 )+β_5 (-1^{t_i})+ε_i$,  nonlinear 
regression with an exogenous variable.
Where 
$t_i$ =1, 2…, 60
and

d = dummy variable with 20 0's and 40 number 1's

```
d=c(rep(0,20),rep(1,40))
```

And an ARIMA model (1,1,1) for $Y_i$. Therefore, I want to estimate simultaneously the $β_i$ and the ARIMA coefficients in order to avoid the confusion between the exogenous coefficients and ARIMA coefficients.  I know that $arima()$ can deal with this formulation but, how do the nonlinear model can be set within function function?. It seems that the *xreg* term only deals with linear parameters.

Comment: As parameterized, your model isn't identifiable (choose some value for $\beta_3/\beta_4$, and then note that doubling both $\beta_3$ and $\beta_4$ leaves that ratio unchanged) - as the model stands, you can only estimate $\beta_3/\beta_4$. You have to fix that problem with your model before even considering trying to estimate it.

Answer (score 5):

Do the parameters $\beta_3$ and $\beta_4$ have any particular interpretation or meaning in the context of your model? You can consider reparameterizing the model merging $\beta_3 t_i /\beta_4$ as $\theta\,t_i$. In this way the model becomes linear in the parameters and you can pass the regressors $t_i$ and $d_t$ through argument `xreg` in function `arima`.

You should include $t_i$ only once in the reparameterized model. In your model, the regressor $t_i$ is proportional to the regressor $2\pi t_i$. With this type of collinearity among the regressors the optimization algorithm won't be able to invert the system matrix.

**Edit** (updated answer for the new model defined in the question)

The function `stats::arima` does not allow you to specify this non-linear parameterization. You should modify the function `arima`, which is not straightforward since would require among other things recompiling the package. You can also try to create your own function, the functions that you would need are essentially: `makeARIMA`, `KalmanLike` and `nlm`, but this is also quite a hard work. You may ask for further guidance at 
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

**Did you find this model in any paper?** If you know some application of this model published in a paper and the data are available, it would be a nice exercise to do and someone could be willing to replicate it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Glen_b and javlacalle . I have edited my post and the model has varied a little. With the new model, $beta_3$ and $beta_4$ have a particular interpretation, period and amplitude of a sinus wave. Is there any way to estimate the ARMA parameters and this model parameters in only a single stage? (not estimating first the NLM and then the ARMA).